# A '50s Yeti movie which has a scene with two men sitting around a fire in a cave

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

There is a movie from the '50s which has a scene with two men sitting around a fire in a cave. One of the men reveals that he is actually a Yeti. Although he is shaven, with a haircut, he opens his collar to show a chest full of dense snow white hair. He hates his companion because they are different species and is about to kill him. The scene fades to black and the murder isn't shown.

Hope this meager description will be enough for someone to identify this movie for me.

Comment: There was probably a similar "Dr. Who" episode in the 1960's.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the film you are looking for is [Man Beast (1956)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049468/?ref_=ttls_li_tt)

> The group is attacked by the snowmen, with the treacherous Varga working against them behind the scenes. Hudson falls off a cliff while being chased by a yeti, and **Dr. Erickson is lured into a cave by Varga**, who then shoots him dead. When most of the party is dead, **Varga reveals to Connie that he is actually a fifth-generation descendant of the Yeti**, who for decades have been kidnapping human women and forcing them to breed with the male snowmen in an attempt to eventually wipe out the yeti strain from their DNA. - [Wikipedia - Man Beast (film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Beast_(film))

[image]

Comment: That's...  not how genetics works.

Comment: @DavidW Actually, if yetis and humans are the same species, that's exactly how it works!

Comment: @CJDennis *technically* DavidW is correct, since "wipe out" is absolute, while Yeti DNA would only be diluted.  For example, Denosovian and Neanderthal DNA still exist in humans.  And if these part-Yetis unknowingly breed with each other then the Yeti DNA will *definitely* be preserved.

Comment: Thank you for quickly answering my question. My next question, is how do I watch this turkey of a movie without paying for it?

Comment: @RonJohn Look up homeopathic remedies for how long it takes for dilution to become nothing left of the original.

Comment: @CJDennis the scale of homeopathic dilution is far beyond that of DNA dilution; otherwise, Denosovian and Neanderthal DNA would have disappeared from the genome.  **But...** they still exist.

Comment: @RonJohn If only a single Neanderthal had interbred with Homo sapiens (not humans, since Homo neanderthalensis and Homo denisova/altaiensis [Denisovans] are also Homo, i.e. human), their DNA would likely have disappeared by now. If you avoid anyone with Yeti DNA interbreeding with others with Yeti DNA, eventually you'll have no Yeti DNA left. It's only when you have a large interbreeding population with most individuals having "foreign" DNA that that DNA can persist indefinitely. Neanderthal DNA is too widely distributed to be "bred out" of Homo sapiens now.

Comment: This is science *fiction*, please check your science at the door.

Comment: @CJ while technically true, your "only a single Neanderthal" scenario does not jibe with the movie: "who **for decades** have been kidnapping human women and forcing them to breed with the male **snowmen**".

Comment: @RonJohn Eventually, they will dilute their genetic pool so much that only the Y (or Yeti) chromosome will remain of their original DNA.